# Is ideal sheaf locally free?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

If $H=\mathbb{P}^k\hookrightarrow \mathbb{P}^n$ is a projective subspace, is it true that $I_H$ is locally free sheaf on $\mathbb{P}^n$ (where $I_H$ is an ideal sheaf of $H$)?

Thanks!

Comment: Also, ideal sheaves are almost never locally free - this happens if and only if the ideal is principal

Comment: @Asal Beag Dubh You're right, let me fix that.

Comment: OK, now @FredrikMeyer answers the revised question completely.